# Compass – Undefined mixin display-box

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to do this

```
@import "compass/css3";
.example {
   @include display-box;
}
```

Basicaly just use mixin from `compass/css3` as described here http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box/

However it gives me this error `Syntax error: Undefined mixin 'display-box'`

My Compass version is `Compass 1.0.0.rc.1 (Polaris)`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your import is incomplete, per [the docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box/). You want:

```
@import "compass/css3/box";
```

Comment: Oh I see... I thought that it would import the whole pack `box` included. (as it's here: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box/) Thanks

Comment: Note that these were deprecated in 1.0 for a reason, you should not be using them.

Comment: In a newer version of Compass you have to use: @import "compass/css3/flexbox";

Read more here: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/flexbox/

Comment: I got this from the watcher 
WARNING: The compass/css3/box module is DEPRECATED and will be removed in the next release. Please use compass/css3/flexbox instead.